# How can I use paths in tsconfig.json?

Tags: typescript, node-modules, tsconfig

I was reading about [path-mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) in file *[tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)*, and I wanted to use it to avoid using the following ugly paths:

[image]

The project organization is a bit weird because we have a mono-repository that contains projects and libraries. The projects are grouped by company and by *browser / server / universal*.

[image]

How can I configure the paths in file *tsconfig.json*, so instead of:

```
import { Something } from "../../../../../lib/src/[browser/server/universal]/...";
```

I can use:

```
import { Something } from "lib/src/[browser/server/universal]/...";
```

Will something else be required in the [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack) configuration? Or is the *tsconfig.json* file enough?

Comment: Have look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/tspath

Comment: See here: https://medium.com/@webia1.github/custom-paths-in-vanilla-typescript-66cfd3f36420

Answer (score 580, accepted):

This can be set up on your *[tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)* file, as it is a [TypeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript) feature.

You can do like this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src", // This must be specified if "paths" is.
         ...
        "paths": {
            "@app/*": ["app/*"],
            "@config/*": ["app/_config/*"],
            "@environment/*": ["environments/*"],
            "@shared/*": ["app/_shared/*"],
            "@helpers/*": ["helpers/*"]
        },
        ...
```

Have in mind that the path, where you want to refer to, takes your baseUrl as the base of the route you are pointing to and it's mandatory as described on the documentation.

*The character '@' is not mandatory.*

After you set it up on that way, you can easily use it like this:

```
import { Yo } from '@config/index';
```

The only thing you might notice is that the intellisense does not work in the current latest version, so I would suggest to follow an index convention for importing/exporting files.

Reference: *[Module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping)*

Comment: Just a comment that might help others... if you are working with node.js or some environment that doesn't use a module bundler like webpack you will additionally need the https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias module

Comment: This works completely fine but there is a problem when enable declaration and import this npm module in another module. Intelisense breaks. Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: @siva - me too. Did you get an answer for this issue?

Comment: @cubabit not exactly. We moved to relative paths instead of aliases. But I found few ts plugin which does it: https://github.com/zerkalica/zerollup/tree/master/packages/ts-transform-paths

Comment: I cannot get this to work. I have a tsconfig.json file, and then inside my src I have a tsconfig.app.json file. I have tried adding these values to both, with and without "*" and slashes. I'm just using angular-cli. Is there anything special that has to be done, like for webpack? Thanks!

Comment: @Aphax yes. it's possible to map to a single file, I prepared an example here: 
https://github.com/ialex90/TypeScript-Node-Starter/commit/a4e8cc1f8f8d5176e0099e05b51f97b0ef4bebea

Comment: @emery.noel You need to add it only once, add it to the global one tsconfig.json

Comment: note that jest-test don't use the tsconfig-paths - you need to define a `moduleNameMapper`: [tsjest#414](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/414)

Comment: this causes issues if you're using Jest BTW as the paths arent resolveable. there's a way to use aliases with jest. But then if you're using node too, it becomes yawnsome to have alias definitions in 4 different places.

Comment: what if the module specified in the `paths` has its own `package.json` and node_modules? during compilation `node_modules` are not included in the `dist` folder

Comment: This answer would be much better, if it would have a warning that this will not work out-of-the-box on nodejs. Without such a warning, nodejs user will inevitably run in the [infamous issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10866) that TypeScript will successfully handle the path aliases at compile time, but since it doesn't rewrite import paths, nodejs will fail importing at runtime.

Comment: Why the hell does no one have the answers to ionic. I guess no one uses it .But I tried about a billion solution similar to this and it doesnt work. I am using ionic 6. everything is just way too outdated

Comment: in order for the paths to work with nodejs you need to pre-load `tsconfig-paths/register` and `ts-node/register/transpile-only`.

Comment: im having a really strange issue. In my compiler it works fine on all the includes but as soon as I try and instantiate the class it cant find the module event though in vs code it finds it etc. Any ideas? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67281799/typescript-aliases-not-working-properly-when-i-init-dependency

Comment: For me setting the `noEmit` option to `true` in the tsconfig.json solved the problem in a node.js environment.

Comment: While it works for me perfectly with not nested imports, no matter wheter it is with @ and/or initial _, it does not woth nested paths like 'assets/icons' again no matter...

Answer (score 45):

You can use a combination of the [`baseUrl` and `paths` documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping).

Assuming root is in the topmost `src` directory (and I read your image properly), use:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "lib/*": [
        "src/org/global/lib/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack), you might also need to add a [module resolution](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/). For Webpack 2, this could look like:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        ...
        modules: [
            ...
            './src/org/global'
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Just noticing @mleko, @alejandro-lora used `baseUrl`, you talk `rootDir` ... — what's the difference?

Answer (score 26):

Check this similar solutions with asterisk

```
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "paths": {
    "*": [
      "node_modules/*",
      "src/types/*"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: I don't see what he did here. What does this do?

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg  for all imports (*)  try to find them on `node_modules` and `src/types`

Comment: But this cannot resolve .css files.

Answer (score 19):

If you are looking for the most minimalist example for referencing your root folder with `@`, this would be it:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"]
    }
  }
}
// Example usage: import * as logUtils from '@/utils/logUtils';
```

Or if you don't even have a `src` folder or would like to explicitly include it in the imports, this would also work:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"]
    }
  }
}
// Example usage: import * as logUtils from '@/src/utils/logUtils';
```

Comment: this breaks imports, like for example I had a `axios.ts` file and I had `import axios from 'axios';` and it was referencing itself and giving me "any" as a result for the type, so I changed the code to `"@/*": ["./src/*"]` and removed `baseUrl`

Answer (score 18):

This works for me:

```
yarn add --dev tsconfig-paths

ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register <your-index-file>.ts
```

This loads all paths in *tsconfig.json*. A sample *tsconfig.json*:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        {…}
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "paths": {
            "assets/*": [ "assets/*" ],
            "styles/*": [ "styles/*" ]
        }
    },
}
```

Make sure you have both baseUrl and paths for this to work.

And then you can import like:

```
import {AlarmIcon} from 'assets/icons'
```

Answer (score 13):

If you are using paths, you will need to change back absolute paths to relative paths for it to work after compiling TypeScript code into plain JavaScript code using `tsc`.

Most popular solution for this has been [tsconfig-paths](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths) so far.

I've tried it, but it did not work for me for my complicated setup.
Also, it resolves paths in run-time, meaning overhead in terms of your package size and resolve performance.

So, I wrote a solution myself, [tscpaths](https://github.com/joonhocho/tscpaths).

I'd say it's better overall because it replaces paths at compile-time. It means there is no runtime dependency or any performance overhead. It's pretty simple to use. You just need to add a line to your build scripts in the [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/) file.

The project is pretty young, so there could be some issues if your setup is very complicated.
It works flawlessly for my setup, though my setup is fairly complex.

Comment: There is a third way: use Vercel's [ncc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vercel/ncc) tool, which compiles your TypeScript project to a single file.

Comment: Use [tsc-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc-alias) instead

Answer (score 11):

If you are using [tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths) and this does not work for you, try `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  // ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@some-folder/*": ["./src/app/some-folder/*", "./dist/app/some-folder/*"],
      // ...
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

If the compiler sees `@some-folder/some-class`, it is trying to find it in `./src...` or in `./dist...`.

Answer (score 8):

[Alejandro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281741/how-can-i-use-paths-in-tsconfig-json/43330003#43330003) worked for me, but as I'm using the `awesome-typescript-loader` with [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack) 4, I also had to add the [`tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin) to my *webpack.config* file for it to resolve correctly.

Answer (score 7):

It’s kind of a relative path.
Instead of the below code

```
import { Something } from "../../../../../lib/src/[browser/server/universal]/...";
```

We can avoid the "../../../../../". It’s looking odd and is not readable either.

So the TypeScript configuration file have answer for the same.
Just specify the baseUrl, config will take care of your relative path.

**Way to configuew:** In the [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) file, add the below properties.

```
"baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": [ "app/*" ],
      "@env/*": [ "environments/*" ]
    }
```

So *finally* it will look like below:

```
import { Something } from "@app/src/[browser/server/universal]/...";
```

It looks simple, awesome and more readable...

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

I'm not sure if we must define the paths. But after write *baseUrl* to *src*.
I can import all folders under the *src* folder like this:

```
import { Home } from "pages";
import { formatDate } from "utils";
import { Navbar } from "components";
```

Don't forget to restart your terminal after change the *tsconfig.json*.

Answer (score 4):

If TypeScript + Webpack 2 + at-loader is being used, there is an additional step ([mleko's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281741/how-can-i-use-paths-in-tsconfig-json/43291186#43291186) was only partially working for me):

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "rootDir": ".",
    "paths": {
      "lib/*": [
        "src/org/global/lib/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}

// webpack.config.js
const { TsConfigPathsPlugin } = require('awesome-typescript-loader');

resolve: {
    plugins: [
        new TsConfigPathsPlugin(/* { tsconfig, compiler } */)
    ]
}
```

[Advanced path resolution in TypeScript 2.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/awesome-typescript-loader#advanced-path-resolution-in-typescript-20)

Comment: Please don't use TsConfigPathsPlugin. It's not well-maintained. There are many open issues regarding webpack v5.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there has been an update to React that doesn't allow you to set the `"paths"` in the *[tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)* file any longer.

Nicely, React just outputs a warning:

> The following changes are being made to your tsconfig.json file: \
>
> - compilerOptions.paths must not be set (aliased imports are not supported)

then updates your *tsconfig.json* and removes the entire `"paths"` section for you. There is a way to get around this run

```
npm run eject
```

This will eject all of the `create-react-scripts` settings by adding `config` and `scripts` directories and build/configuration files into your project. This also allows ***a lot more control*** over how everything is built, named, etc. by updating the `{project}/config/*` files.

Then update your *tsconfig.json* file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        {…}
        "paths": {
            "assets/*": [ "assets/*" ],
            "styles/*": [ "styles/*" ]
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: Another workaround for this would be to inherit those values from another file.

In your tsconfig, place this param and path to the base file

```
{
 ...
 "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
 ...
}
```

Then in the `tsconfig.base.json` you can place your paths config
```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
  "paths": {
   "*": ["*"]
  }
 }
}
```

The error will still show, but it wont delete your settings anymore.

There's more info on why this is happening here
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10178#issuecomment-860247467

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with just [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) by using [Subpath patterns](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-patterns).

For example, adding this to your `package.json`...

```json
{
    "imports": {
        "#lib": "./build/path/to/lib",
        "#lib/*": "./build/path/to/lib/*",
    }
}
```

will let you import like so, avoiding relative paths.

```js
import { something } from "#lib"
```

Note that they must start with a hash, and in [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/), they must point to your build so Node can recognize it.

Like others have said, you can add something like this to your *tsconfig.json* for TypeScript:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "#lib": ["./src/path/to/lib"],
            "#lib/*": ["./src/path/to/lib/*"],
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### For a component library

If you are working on a library that returns UI components (like react-bootstrap or [Ant Design](https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce)) then this should work for you.

```
"compilerOptions": {
        ....
        "rootDir": "src",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "src/*": ["src/*"],
            "components/*": ["src/components/*"],
        }
  },
```

Comment: Why emphasize the `rootDir` here?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the compiler operation using [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

I have added *baseUrl* in the file for a project like below:

`"baseUrl": "src"`

It is working fine. So add your base directory for your project.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for 2021.

*Note: [CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/). Initially the idea of ​​using a third party library or ejecting app for alias seemed crazy to me. However, after 8 hours of searching (and trying variant with eject), it turned out that this option is the least painful.*

Step 1.

```
yarn add --dev react-app-rewired react-app-rewire-alias
```

Step 2.
Create ***config-overrides.js*** file in your project's root and fill it with:

```
const {alias} = require('react-app-rewire-alias')

module.exports = function override(config) {
  return alias({
    assets: './src/assets',
    '@components': './src/components',
  })(config)
}
```

Step 3. Fix your ***package.json*** file:

```
  "scripts": {
-   "start": "react-scripts start",
+   "start": "react-app-rewired start",
-   "build": "react-scripts build",
+   "build": "react-app-rewired build",
-   "test": "react-scripts test",
+   "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

If @declarations don't work, add them to the *d.ts* file.
For example:
`'@constants': './src/constants'`, => add in ***react-app-env.d.ts*** `declare module '@constants';`

That is all. Now you can continue to use yarn or npm start/build/test commands as usual.

[Full version in documentation.](https://github.com/oklas/react-app-rewire-alias)

Note: The *Using with TypeScript / JavaScript configuration* part in docs **did not work** for me. The error "aliased imports are not supported" when building the project remained. So I used an easier way. Luckily it works.

Comment: `react-app-rewired` package is [lightly maintained](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired#rewire-your-app-) so you shouldn't continue with this package you should use **craco** instead

Comment: I tried installing `craco` today and noticed there were around 20 out of date dependencies, some with critical vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

`/` starts from the root only. To get the relative path, we should use `./` or `../`.

Comment: Not true. Many options allow for [non-relative module imports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html).

Answer (score 0):

`baseUrl` being correct is important.

```
import Home from '@app/features/Home';
```

`src/features/Home.tsx`

```json
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": [
        "src/*"
      ],
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "paths": {
            "@styles/*": ["assets/scss/*"]
        }
    },
}
```

That was causing me issues.

Answer (score 0):

For me, [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) was not recognizing the path, but the project was building just fine. The issue was that I had the `paths` declaration in a second *tsconfig.app.json* file.

Moving the `paths` property from *tsconfig.app.json* into *[tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)* fixed the issue.

---

Supposedly, this is because Visual Studio Code only checks the first *tsconfig.json* file found in the root directory of the project, although I haven't confirmed that for myself. Perhaps someone can provide a comment with more information.