# define path in tsconfig.app.json for angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, import, angular-cli, tsconfig

The project was generated via angular CLI. I have the following folder structure:

[image]

I want to define a path to a **bar** folder in **tsconfig.app.json** and import `Car` to `Garage`.

My **tsconfig.app.json**:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths" : {
      "@bar" : ["foo/bar"]
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

My **Garage.ts**:

```
import { Car } from "@bar/Car";
export class Garage {}
```

In garage.ts I have an error:

> Cannot find module '@bar/car'.

Comment: you will find [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/configuring-typescript-compiler-a84ed8f87e3#06ea) helpful, it explains how and why use `paths` quite elaborately

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com, Thank you sir. I went through the article briefly, but still don't get it. Can you please give some insights on why the `Car` module can not be resolved in that particular example ?

Comment: I've posted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46640069/2545680)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define `paths` like that:

```
   "paths" : {
      "@bar/*" : [
          "foo/bar/*"
      ]
    },
```

For more information read

- [Configuring TypeScript compiler](https://blog.angularindepth.com/configuring-typescript-compiler-a84ed8f87e3)

Comment: Thank you sir, it solved the original problem, however the editor (in my case VS code) still complains '[ts] Cannot find module '@bar/Car'.'

Comment: @koryakinp, sorry, I'm not familiar with VSCode. Consider asking separate question

Comment: The trailing * in the path itself (foo/bar/*) was the crux in my case.

Answer (score 5):

Please do not forget to put the `baseUrl` first before adding the `paths`. I spent hours trying to figure out where I was wrong.

```
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work

```
    {
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths" : {
      "@bar" : ["foo/bar"],
      "@environment/*": ["environments/*"],
        "@shared/*": ["app/_shared/*"],
        "@helpers/*": ["helpers/*"]
       //you can define multiple paths inside this 
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

and the question looks like **duplicate** of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281741/how-to-use-paths-in-tsconfig-json)

Comment: Sorry, it was actually `"paths" : { "@bar" : ["foo/bar"]},`

Comment: edited my code to provide additional details@koryakinp

Answer (score 0):

to stop the complain in VS code : CMD + SHIFT + P then type reload or Reload Project
to stop the complain in webstorm : invalidating caches (File | Invalidate caches, Invalidate and restart)