# How to share code between TypeScript projects?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have two projects with following file structure

```
/my-projects/

  /project-a/
    lib.ts
    app.ts
    tsconfig.json

  /project-b/
    app.ts         // import '../project-a/lib.ts'
    tsconfig.json
```

**I want to consume `lib.ts` located in `project-a` also from `project-b`. How to do that?**

- Release it as **NPM module - absolutely don't want that**, it's an overkill for such a simple use case. I just 
  want to share one file between two projects.
- Use `import '../project-a/lib.ts'` - doesn't work, TypeScript complains

`'lib.ts' is not under 'rootDir'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.`

- Put `tsconfig.json` one level up so it would cover both `project-a` and `project-b` - can't do that, the TypeScript config is slightly different for those projects. Also it's not very convenient, don't want to do that.

Any other ways?

Comment: Two suggestions: a) you could put `project-a` on GitHub, [and then add that to your `project-b` package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#github-urls), or b) you could use [`tsconfig` inheritance to share a config and then just override things for the two packages](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#configuration-inheritance-with-extends).

Comment: It's also possible to [use local paths as NPM dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths), if you'd rather not make your code public.

Comment: so did you find a solution to sharing the code between angular and express apps?

Answer (score 133):

Since Typescript 3.0 this can be done with Project References.

Typescript docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html

I believe you would have to move lib.ts into a small ts project called something like 'lib'

The lib project should have a tsconfig containing:

```
// lib/tsconfig.json
    {
          "compilerOptions": {
            /* Truncated compiler options to list only relevant options */
            "declaration": true, 
            "declarationMap": true,
            "rootDir": ".",   
            "composite": true,     
          },
          "references": []  // * Any project that is referenced must itself have a `references` array (which may be empty).
        }
```

Then in both project-a and project-b add the reference to this lib project into your tsconfig

```
// project-a/ts-config.json
// project-b/ts-config.json
{
        "compilerOptions": {
            "target": "es5", 
            "module": "es2015",
            "moduleResolution": "node"
            // ...
        },
        "references": [
            { 
                "path": "../lib",
                // add 'prepend' if you want to include the referenced project in your output file
                "prepend": true, 
            }
        ]
    }
```

In the lib project. Create a file index.ts which should export all your code you want to share with other projects.

```
// lib/index.ts    
export * from 'lib.ts';
```

Now, let's say lib/lib.ts looks like this:

```
// lib/lib.ts
export const log = (message: string) => console.log(message);
```

You can now import the log function from lib/lib.ts in both project-a and project-b

```
// project-a/app.ts 
// project-b/app.ts
import { log } from '../lib';
log("This is a message");
```

Before your intelissense will work, you now need to build both your project-a and project-b using:

```
tsc -b
```

Which will first build your project references (lib in this case) and then build the current project (project-a or project-b).

The typescript compiler will not look at the actual typescript files from lib. Instead it will only use the typescript declaration files (*.d.ts) generated when building the lib project.

That's why your lib/tsconfig.json file must contain:

```
"declaration": true,
```

However, if you navigate to the definition of the log function in project-a/app.ts using F12 key in Visual Studio code, you'll be shown the correct typescript file.
At least, if you have correctly setup your lib/tsconfig.json with:

```
"declarationMap": true,
```

I've create a small github repo demonstrating this example of project references with typescript:

https://github.com/thdk/TS3-projects-references-example

Comment: Thank you! The only thing that's not working so well is: I'm trying to put my `.ts` files in `src`, and setup my `tsconfig` with `rootDir: './src'` and `outDir: `./lib`. Problem is when I want to reference one of these files in another project, the `import` statement is now all wrong. I'd do `import {something} from "../../dep/src/something.ts"`... But after build, that path is wrong, it should get the `js` file from `../../dep/lib/something.js`. But TypeScript is not doing this transformation. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ArashMotamedi simply change your import to "../../dep/lib/something". This will only be available after your project reference  ('dep') has been built.

Comment: Great answer, but from what I'm seeing (I definitely could have messed something up), if I were to push "project-a" to production as a standalone project, the referenced lib would not be bundled with the code. It seems that you'd need to push the parent folder containing both project-a *and* the referenced lib. Perhaps webpack is necessary to "inline" the referenced lib? I may have a different use case than the OP...all I'm trying to do is have some loose typescript files that I want to be a "single sources of truth" rather than copy and paste them to various projects.

Comment: @devuxer have you found a proper solution for your attempt?

Comment: @da-chiller, I haven't. The only solution I've found is to put all code in the same project.

Comment: Does this help you? I've updated my answer with the optioal prepend option. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#prepend-with-outfile

Comment: what if your `lib` folder has package.json with dependencies?

Comment: You'll have to make sure they are installed before you run tsc -b.

Comment: I get this error, when using `prepend` option: Cannot prepend project 'some/path/to/lib' because it does not have 'outFile' set.

Comment: @UserRebo Ah I'm sorry, prepend will probably only work when you are using a single outputFile for each project. Which only works for system or amd modules or when using modules resolution : none

Comment: Thanks for this. This solution worked for me. However I wanted to add an `outDir` in the `tsconfig.json` for common folder so that all the bulit files are put there. But this broke the build for project-a and project-b. What do I need to do to make the build work again?

Comment: @dragonfly02 the common code will be included in both project a and b. If you don't want this behavior, remove the 'prepend' property from tsconfig files. Make sure to read the docs to understand what each setting is tsconfig does.

Comment: @ThdK I do want the common to be referenceable by both projects. Currently, if I build project a or b, the `js`, `d.ts`, `d.ts.map` files for the common code is outputed to `lib` folder, whereas I want to output them to `lib/dist` folder leaving only ts files in the `lib` folder. When setting `outDir` for the common code to be `./dist`, project a and b don't build complaining about not being able to find referenced module from the commone code.

Comment: silly little harmless thing, projects that are referenced *dont*, in fact, need to have a `references` empty array. i say "harmless" because it doesn't affect the output either way

Comment: Unluckily `prepend` is now deprecated: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51909

Comment: @dragonfly02 is right, if there's an outDir set in a and b e.g. "outDir" : "dist" the built files will be in project-a/dist/ and project-b/dist/ but running node project-a/dist/app-a.js will throw a 'module not found error' as app-a.js is importing relative to it's .ts file location ('../common/index') but it should now be '../../common/index' as app-a.js is not in the project-a folder but project-a/dist

Comment: This works well, but using `tsc -b` adds a bunch of .map and .js files to my folder, which I then have to delete. Is there a way of avoiding that?

Answer (score 37):

This can be achieved with use of 'paths' property of 'CompilerOptions' in tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@otherProject/*": [
        "../otherProject/src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

Below is a screenshot of folder structure.

[image]

Below is content of tsconfig.json which references other ts-project

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./tsc-out",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": [ "src/*" ],
      "@qc/*": [
        "../Pti.Web/ClientApp/src/app/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "tsc-out"
  ]
}
```

Below is import statement to reference exports from other project.

```
import { IntegrationMessageState } from '@qc/shared/states/integration-message.state';
```

Comment: Are you sure [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43281741/264031) is only valid when it's sharing within the *same* (tsconfig) project?

Comment: @NicholasPetersen, I use this approach with two different tsconfig files in two different folders

Comment: Ok, interesting, I tried it and it wasn't working, so I figured this didn't actually work across projects. Maybe I need to re-try it. Would you be so kind to share a fuller project structure so I could try to duplicate this in a simple hello-world way?

Comment: @NicholasPetersen, please see attached screenshot of folder structure, tsconfig.json and import statement

Comment: Thank you @Oleg! That was helpful. I think my problem was this: The initial import (`import { IntegrationMessageState } ...`) seemed to work, but when I called members on the imported type, even though the type was recognized, none of its members were available, so I thought it was failing. Well duh, I was accessing directly on the type and not on a `new` instance of it (or call prototype property). So I think it had been working. FYI: Not sure the exact difference, but I ended up using the new project reference route: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html

Comment: @NicholasPetersen, in my project I can access any nested objects of imported object. Maybe something wrong (special) with your particular classes? BTW, thank you for the link of new typescript 3.0 feature

Comment: Most useful SO answer I've seen in a while

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work when importing shared enum types, any idea why? In that case it gives the error: `Module not found: You attempted to import /shared/declarations which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.`

Comment: I solved relative imports issue by adding one more path. project1 tsconfig.json
paths: {
 "@prj1/*": [ "src/*" ],
}

there are imports in project1 like
import { Something } from '@prj1/some-path';

project2 tsconfig.json
paths: {
 "@prj2/*": [ "src/*" ],
    "@prj1/*": [ "../Project1/src/*"
}

Project2 is not allowed to have allias @prj1

Comment: have anyone tried this for node.js? where `shared` folder would have its own package.json with modules?

Comment: Thanks, this worked (mostly)! I use a directory for Typescript interfaces which are used by my frontend and my backend. I defined `"paths": {"@interfaces/*": ["../interfaces/*"]}` in frontend's and backend's `tsconfig.json`. Two caveats: 1. VS Code would only stop complaining after a restart. 2. While I could do `import { MyInterface } from '@interfaces/my.interface'`, I could not define an `interfaces/index.ts` and then do `import { MyInterface } from '@interfaces'`. Somehow the compiler would not accept that.

Answer (score 11):

I think that @qqilihq is on the right track with their response - Although there are the noted potential problems with manually maintaining the contents of a `node_modules` directory.

I've had some luck managing this by using [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) (although there are a number of other similar tools out there, for example [yarn workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/) seem to be somewhat similar, although I've not used them myself).

I'll just say upfront that this might be a little heavyweight for what you're talking about, but it does give your project a lot of flexibility to grow in the future.

With this pattern, your code would end up looking something like:

```
/my-projects/
    /common-code/
        lib.ts
        tsconfig.json
        package.json
    /project-a/
        app.ts (Can import common-code)
        tsconfig.json
        package.json (with a dependency on common-code)
    /project-b/
        app.ts (Can import common-code)
        tsconfig.json
        package.json (with a dependency on common-code)
```

The general theory here is that the tool creates symlinks between your internal libraries and the `node_modules` directories of their dependant packages.

The main pitfalls I've encountered doing this are

- `common-code` has to have both a `main` and `types` property set in its `package.json` file
- `common-code` has to be compiled before any of its dependencies can rely on it
- `common-code` has to have `declaration` set to true in its `tsconfig.json`

My general experience with this has been pretty positive, as once you've got the basic idea understood, there's very little 'magic' in it, its simply a set of standard node packages that happen to share a directory.

Comment: After adding the projectB in package.json as 'projectB: file:../projectB'; and then in a class like this : import ClassB from 'projectB/package/ClassB';

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm the only dev working on 2 projects which require some shared code folder I've setup a 2-way [real time sync](https://www.goodsync.com/) between the common code shared folders.

```
project A
 - shared/ -> 2-way sync with project B
 - abc/

project B
 - shared/ -> 2-way sync with project A
 - xyz/
```

It's a one-time quick setup but gives benefits like:

- no hassle of configuring and managing mono-repo/multiple tsconfig
- no build step to get latest code, works instantly
- works with cloud build tools as shared code is inside repo instead of `symlink`
- easier to debug locally as all files are within the project
- I can further put checks on shared folder with commit hooks/husky and throw warnings etc.

And in-case if I want to collaborate with other team members, I can mention to use this sync tool as part of project setup.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases using symlink for dependencies is the easiest way, sometimes it also make sense to symlink `tsconfig.json`.

It won't work for all cases, but it works for many, especially if used with `bun` or `deno`.

Answer (score -1):

It seems we've got a few options here:

(1) Put both projects in a mono repo and use answer given by @ThdK using TS project references

NOT GOOD if you don't want a mono repo

(2) Use Lerna - see answer by @metric_caution

NOT GOOD if you can't be bothered to learn Lerna / don't want to publish your shared files to npm

(3) Create a shared npm package

NOT GOOD if you don't want to publish your shared files to npm

(4) Put shared folders in a "shared" directory in project A and write a script to copy files in the shared folder from project A to project B's shared folder that is executed on a git push OR a script to sync the two folders.

Here the script can be executed manually when copying / syncing is required. The copying / syncing could also be done prior to a git push using husky and the shared files added to git automatically in the script.

Since I don't want a mono repo and I can't be bothered to publish an npm package for such a pathetic purpose I'm gonna go with option 4 myself.

Comment: You can also publish your packages on github packages instead of npm.

Answer (score -5):

In a similar scenario, where I also wanted to avoid the overhead of having to perform an NPM release, I went for the following structure (after lots of trial and error and failed attempts):

```
/my-projects/

  /node_modules/
    /my-lib/
      lib.ts
      tsconfig.json
      package.json

  /project-a/
    app.ts
    tsconfig.json

  /project-b/
    app.ts         
    tsconfig.json
```

The central idea is to move the shared stuff to a `node_modules` directory above the individual projects (this exploits NPMs loading mechanism, which would start looking for dependencies in the current directory and then move upwards).

So, `project-a` and `project-b` can now access the lib simply via `import { Whatever } from 'my-lib'`.

**Notes:**

1. In my case, `my-lib` is actually only for shared **typings** (i.e. `.d.ts` files within a `lib` subdirectory). This means, I do not explicitly need to build `my-lib` and my `my-lib/package.json` looks as follows:

   ```
   {
     "name": "my-types",
     "version": "0.0.0",
     "private": true,
     "types": "lib/index"
   }
   ```
2. In case `my-lib` contains runnable code, you’ll obviously need to build `my-lib`, so that `.js` files are generated, and add a `"main"` property to the `package.json` which exposes the main `.js` file.
3. **Most important:** Despite its name, `/my-projects/node_modules` **only** contains custom code, no **installed** dependencies (they are actually in the individual projects `project-a/node_modules` and `project-b/node_modules`). This means, there’s an explicit git ignore setting, which **un**-ignores the `/node_modules` directory from being committed.

Is this a clean solution? Probably not not. Did it solve my issue? Yes. Am I happy to hear about improvement suggestions? Absolutely!

Comment: that sucks - `node_modules` is often deleted. You can't expect people or even yourself to remember that you customized `node_modules` folder. You shouldn't mess with it

Comment: @Toolkit Feel free to suggest a better solution. As we're using the root `node_module` **only** for custom modules, it worked fine within our team, and neither me nor my colleagues accidentally deleted anything. It includes a readme file which explains the motivation and an adjusted `.gitignore` file. Again -- better suggestions welcome.

Comment: I played with this solution and the `my-lib` doesn't compile because ts compiler doesn't look for imported npm modules in its local `node_modules`, seems like it looks in the upper one which is not a real one. If I rename `/my-projects/node_modules/` into `/my-projects/xxx/` the lib starts compiling fine. Any ideas?

Comment: @qqilihq I want to thank you for offering this solution, in light of the downvotes. I realize this stuff just absolutely stinks, so we have to try and adopt un-ideal solutions. Anyways, cheerio.