# Typescript library import with sub paths

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a Typescript library that is being consumed from a React app. I wanted to import the TS library contents with sub-paths like

```
import {base} from "my-lib"
import {foo} from "my-lib/path1"
import {bar} from "my-lib/path2"
```

I came across the [Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33079) which states that this is not yet supported (`exports` in package.json) by Typescript. I'm using Typescript 4.3.

There is a workaround posted in the same thread - Github repo [typescript-subpath-exports-workaround](https://github.com/teppeis/typescript-subpath-exports-workaround). It uses `exports` and `typeVersions`

```
{
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist-types/index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": "./dist/index.js",
    "./exported": "./dist/exported.js"
  },
  "typesVersions": {
    "*": {
      "exported": ["dist-types/exported"]
    }
  }
}
```

I created a new react app (via `npx create-react-app` command) and tried importing `hello` from `typescript-subpath-exports-workaround` and it worked fine. But couldn't import `typescript-subpath-exports-workaround/exported

```
import {hello} from "typescript-subpath-exports-workaround" //works fine
import {foo} from "typescript-subpath-exports-workaround/exported" //gives "Module not found" error
```

Full error is below:

```
./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'typescript-subpath-exports-workaround/exported' in '/Users/...../my-react-app/src'
```

Codesandbox code - https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-forked-5yxd8

**UPDATE:** The sub-path used in import and the folder structure are different. In the above example, there won't be a folder named `path1` or `path2`.

Comment: What!? Typescript can't do this? What a shame.

Answer (score 0):

This block in my `package.json` worked for me:

```
{
    // ...
    "files": [
        "/dist"
    ],
    "main": "./dist/index.js",
    "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
    "exports": {
        ".": "./dist/index.js",
        "./types": "./dist/types/index.js",
        "./generate": "./dist/generate/index.js"
    },
    "typesVersions": {
        "*": {
            "types": [
                "./dist/types/index.d.ts"
            ],
            "generate": [
                "./dist/generate/index.d.ts"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "extends": "@tsconfig/node14/tsconfig.json",
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "module": "ESNext"
    }
}
```

And this is my file structure:

```
package.json
tsconfig.json
dist/ // and all its subfolders
src/
  generate/
    index.ts
  types/
    index.ts
  index.ts
```

Separately, I'm using TypeScript 4.7.4. Supposedly the `exports` field is supported with this version, but it didn't work for me. But this (maybe overly complex) workaround worked for me.

Answer (score -3):

As answered in [How to create a local module in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53716994/11667949):

> Using [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) package might solve your problem.
>
> Add this configuration below into package.json:

```
"_moduleAliases": {    "my-module":
"<your_build_folder>/modules/my-module" },
```

And this code on first line

> of your main file (server.ts/index.ts)
>
> `import 'module-alias/register'`;