# How to build typescript project references with visual studio

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, msbuild

I have three folders in my visual studio 2017 solution.

- project-a
- project-b
- lib

Each of these folders have a tsconfig.json file. I have setup these tsconfig files according to the typescript docs and to my older SO answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54772741/681803

In visual studio code, I simply change my build script in my package.json from `tsc` to `tsc --build`. That will build all project listed in my project references list of my tsconfig.

However, I can't find out now how to do the same with visual studio 2017 (for another project)

When I build visual studio project-a (or project-b), it fails to build as the compiler can't find the references of the lib project (not build yet).

When I first manually run `tsc` in the common folder before building project-a or project-b, it does compile because the output folder now already contains the typescript definition files of the lib project which are needed for project-a and project-b.

How to setup visual studio 2017 to work with typescript project references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I just found it when I was looking one more time at the typescript docs...

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#msbuild

> If you have an msbuild project, you can enable build mode by adding

```
<TypeScriptBuildMode>true</TypeScriptBuildMode>
```

> to your proj file. This will enable automatic incremental build as
>   well as cleaning.

After updating my csproj file of my visual studio project with this flag, all project references are nicely being build.

Comment: Hi ThdK, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)