# How to import typescript file from outside of the project folder

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, rollup, svelte-3

So I'm making a svelte typescript library and the folder structure is as follows

```
|- dist/
|- src/
  |- components/
  |- index.ts
|- tests/ 
  |- src/
  |- components/
  |- index.ts
  |- package.json
  |- tsconfig.json
  |- rollup.config.js
|- package.json
|- tsconfig.json
|- rollup.config.js
```

in `tests` folder I have a separate svelte typescript project to test the library and I'm trying to import the files from outside the `tests` folder directly to `tests` project, it gave me this error

```
[!] Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
..\src\utilities\navbarStore.ts (1:12)
1: import type { NavThemes } from "src/interfaces";
               ^
2: import { writable } from "svelte/store";
```

I've tried several stuff like using paths in `tests` project `tsconfig.json` and adding `rootDirs`, still doesn't fix the problem, anyone knows how to tackle this issue? thanks for your help

here's the main project's tsconfig.json :

```
{
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules/*", "public/*", "tests/*", "docs/*", "demo/*"],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
        "target": "es2017",
        "module": "esnext",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": ".",
        "composite": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noErrorTruncation": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "noEmit": false,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "types": ["svelte", "node"],
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

here's `tests` project tsconfig.json :

```
{
    "include": ["src/**/*", "../src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules/*", "__sapper__/*", "public/*"],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
        "target": "es2017",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noErrorTruncation": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "types": ["svelte", "node"],
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "rootDirs": [".", "../"],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "svelteprojectts/*": ["../src/*"],
            "svelteprojectjs/*": ["../dist/es/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your build setup. Could you post your `package.json` and bundle config (`rollup.config.js`) ?

Comment: @dummdidumm thanks for taking your time to reply, fortunately i have found another stackoverflow question that tackled this issue, and i think this is the solution that i was looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729344/how-to-share-code-between-typescript-projects