# TypeScript Path mapping in Visual Studio Code with Intellisense/Auto import

Tags: c#, typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig, typescript-2.5

When I refer classes in another files, intellisense show me a bulb with the required import in VS Code. Sadly, this is not the case when [path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) is used.

```
"baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@shared-vb/*": [
        "../shared/vb/*"
      ]
    },
    "rootDirs": [
      ".",
      "../shared"
    ]
```

If we have a class `vb-sessioninfo.ts` in `../shared/vb`, we can import them cleanly using `import VbSessionInfo from '@shared-vb/vb-sessioninfo'` Normally, when I type `VbSessionInfo`  I get an insellisense bulb with suggestions. But not in this case, I got no suggestion. The import itself works, when I type `import VbSessionInfo from '@shared-vb/vb-sessioninfo'` manually.

### Background: Clean, flexible imports like in **C#**

I want to avoid hard coded imports like `import .. from '../shared/module-folder/module`. They're unflexible and [can result in long nasty statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281741/how-to-use-paths-in-tsconfig-json). We may have to change a lot of wrong imports if a file is moved in another folder of the filesystem. So my idea is to get some replacement for namespaces in C#. path mapping seems a good idea here: Altough it's no automatically resolving like in C#, we can define the real folders in a single place (`tsconfig.json`). This speed up development and prevent me from wasting time in search/replace.

### Environment

- Typescript 2.5.3
- Visual Studio Code 1.17.2 on Arch Linux
- App targets NodeJS in the latest version at time of writing (9.5.0)

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I'm having exactly the same problem