# how to set paths in tsconfig in vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a folder structure like this

```
--src
   -services
      test.ts
   -pages
     -testFolder
       -testFolder.vue
--tsconfig.json
```

Now in the testFolder.vue i am trying to access test.ts .
I wrote like this **`../../services/test`**, this is working. Is there any possibility that i can use some thing like this **`./services/test`** or **services/test**. How do i configure in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281741/how-to-use-paths-in-tsconfig-json I haven't tried it but I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **baseUrl**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  }
}
```

This way when you use absolute paths (like `services/test`), it will look in the folder `./src`.

Comment: This is working thanks. Is there any other way, i have line in webpack `'@': resolve('src')` . so if i use @/services/test working while building, but it is not in parallel with tsconfig. Is there any possibility that i can config in tsconfig.js to go with @/services/...

Comment: is this possible in tsconfig.js, or do i need to change it in the webpack only? why i want to change it in the tsconfig.js because in my project the paths and all are started with @/... .

Comment: Try adding `"paths: {"@/*": ["src/*"]}` to the compilerOptions in your tsconfig