# how to configure an angular project tsconfig paths[] without linting errors?

Tags: angular, typescript, lint

We have the following config in our **tsconfig.ts**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "@pages/*": ["app/pages/*"]
      ...
    },
```

Then we can use much cleaner imports in our other ts files, something like this:

```
import {UrlConstants} from '@app/common/constants/url-constants';
```

Problem comes while linting the project:

```
Module '@app/common' is not listed as dependency in package.json
```

Any way to solve it without going back to using `./***/***/` for imports?

Comment: You are evidently using a custom lint rule and that lint rule is broken. Disable the rule and file an issue

Comment: @AluanHaddad custom lint rule? https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-implicit-dependencies/ this is the rule I think.

Comment: Ah it's part of the official rules. Thanks for the reference. You can disable the rule or whitelist modules as it says. I still say that this is a bug in the rule though. In a number of situations, paths are not simply a convenience.

Comment: @AluanHaddad whitelist modules? Can you please give an example :) Thanks and btw you can submit an answer instead of a comment. Also I have seen this discussion, which seems to follow a similar pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281741/how-to-use-paths-in-tsconfig-json

Comment: Well I don't think I answered any question since the document you yourself just linked shows how to configure the rule with a whitelist. All I have to add is my grumpy opinion that path mapping matters.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I am trying to understand how to create a whitelist based on the doc I provided, but I cannot. Can you please give an example / hint? Thanks! Also an interesting topic: https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3364

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure the rule with a whitelist as documented here https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-implicit-dependencies

That will look like this:

**tslint.json**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "no-implicit-dependencies": [
      true,
      [
        "app",
        "pages"
      ],
      "dev"
    ]
  }
}
```

The "dev" option isn't really for your scenario but it is useful if you lint your tests as I like to do.

Personally, I think the rule should be smarter and attempt to parse a tsconfig for paths to some extent. Sometimes one has many paths and not everyone uses NPM. JSPM users might have to just disable the rule which is a shame because the rule is very well motivated and very useful if you don't hit this rough edge.

This should now work for `@` prefixed paths as https://github.com/palantir/tslint/pull/4192 has been merged. Until you can upgrade you may need to use `"app"` and `"pages"`.

Comment: @DenissM. Damn it looks like this wont work for `@` prefixed paths until https://github.com/palantir/tslint/pull/4192 is merged

Comment: Yep, also got this impression while browsing their github... Well then we have two choices - rename all to app (without @) or switch back to regular imports.

Comment: Or turn off the rule till they fix the damn thing. That's definitely what I would do.