# How to use paths in tsconfig for a single module?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

This question is a follow-on from [How to use paths in tsconfig.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43281741/49942) except I want to do it for a single module.

I have a module:

- It's implemented in `src/functions/foo.ts`
- Its contents are:

  ```
  export default interface Bar {
  }
  ```
- It's imported by another module elsewhere using a non-relative path:

  ```
  import * as Foo from "foo"
  ```

The compiler doesn't find it:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'foo'
```

---

This tsconfig doesn't fix that problem ...

`{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noEmit": true,
        "strict": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es2017",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "build",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "foo": ["src/functions/*"],
            "*": [
                "node_modules/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*", "./typings/**/*", "./test/**/*", "./test-integration/**/*"
    ]
}`

... but this does:

`"paths": {
            "*": [
                "node_modules/*",
                "src/functions/*"
            ]
        }`

---

Why didn't the first version of `paths` work --- what was I doing wrong, what can I do to ensure that `"src/functions/*"` is used only when importing `foo` (and not when importing `*`)?

(I'm using tsc version 3.1.6 on Windows with Node.js).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning a word `foo` to the content of a directory `src/functions/*`.

But `foo` like that can only be used to specify the exact location of a single file (module), without a wildcard, so, like this:

```
"paths": {
    "foo": ["src/functions/foo"],
    "*": [
        "node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

---

What you are probably looking for is

```
"paths": {
    "foo/*": ["src/functions/*"],
    "*": [
        "node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

(`foo/*` instead of `foo`)

Comment: Thank you, it was the first one I was looking for. I think the second would be used if I wanted to import something from `src/functions/bar.ts` by using `import * as BAR from "@foo/bar"`