# Typescript paths not resolving

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsconfig

[Here](https://github.com/oleersoy/typescript-paths)'s the Github MCVE showing an issue. `npm run compile` shows the error.

I'm trying to do this:

```
import {Todo} from '@test';
```

But it's not resolving.

> src/index.ts:1:20 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@test'.

I have `paths` in `tsconfig.json`.

```
  "baseUrl": "./",                          /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
  "paths": {
    "@fs/": ["src/"], 
    "@test/": ["test/"]
  },                                        /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
```

Thoughts?

### Github Typescript Issue

[I opened a bug report for this here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30619) since per some of the comments it should have worked.

Typescript note that I updated the github repository removing the glob patterns and slashes in `@test`.

Comment: [In the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) under path mapping they have set the base url to just `.`

Comment: @pmkro `.` and `./` resolve to the same directory, the contrary would be a TS implementation bug

Comment: @NinoFiliu I figured as much

Comment: For those who are not using a bundler (CRA, webpack, Nextjs, etc) and are stuck with this problem, maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73346203/8221175

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't adjust the VS Code Import Module Specifier settings (as per some answers floating around). And don't remove the glob patterns. In fact add some more in:

```
 "baseUrl": "./",
  "paths": {
    "@fs/*": ["src/*"], 
    "@test/*": ["test/*"]
  },
```

Notice that the glob is in the key AND the value. This is hilariously hard to spot sometimes.

Where the target is a file, the glob should be omitted from key and value.

Comment: You sir, are brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the glob patterns:

```
"paths": {
  "@test": "./test"
}
```

Your solution is weirdly supposed to work, but [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) use no globs and [there have been some reported intellisense bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281741/how-to-use-paths-in-tsconfig-json/43330003#43330003) when using globs.

Comment: Well, yes, and also [this article](https://netbasal.com/sexier-imports-in-typescript-e3c645bdd3c6) says the same. But on my machine, removing the glob pattern made the whole thing work as expected, and adding them back provoked a bug. That's enough to be an answer for me.

Comment: IMO there is definitely a bug in somewhere between my IDE and TS' implementation, but still, if a fix works for someone, it has value as an answer

Comment: I tried removing the glob pattern and it still does not resolve for me.  I pushed the changes to the github repository.

Comment: Also the issue is separate from VSCode.  I'm running `npm run compile` configured in the `package.json` and the `src/index.ts:1:20 - error TS2307:  Cannot find module '@test'` ` is still logged.

Comment: You didn't say I wrote ;) it's `"@test": ["./test"]`, not `"@test/": ["./test/"]`. No slash.