# Trouble converting project to Typescript paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

[So I asked this question earlier today on how to use paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55383929/typescript-paths-not-resolving).

Now I'm trying to convert [this project](https://github.com/fireflysemantics/validator) using that approach.

So I first clone it:

```
git clone git@github.com:fireflysemantics/validator.git
```

Then edit the `paths` setting so it looks like this:

```
"baseUrl": "./",                          /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
"paths": {
  "@fs": ["./src"], 
  "@test": ["./test"]
},                                        /*
```

Then I tried editing the `src/container/error/index.ts` so that it looks like this:

```
export { ObjectErrors } from "@fs/container/error/ObjectErrors";
export { ValidationError } from "./ValidationError";
```

When I compile Typescript still generates this error:

> src/container/error/index.ts:1:30 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@fs/container/error/ObjectErrors'.

1 export { ObjectErrors } from "@fs/container/error/ObjectErrors";
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Thoughts?

### Typescript Github Issue

[Filed an Issue with Typescript here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30619)

Answer (score -1):

Add your paths property to the compilerOptions in the tsconfig file.

```
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {      
      "@app/*": [
        "./app/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just double checked - AFAIK it's in the `compilerOptions` section ...?

Comment: Did you not look at the sample config object?, it is in the compilerOptions section

Comment: [This is the config I'm converting](https://github.com/fireflysemantics/validator/blob/master/tsconfig.json).  I first created a minimal MVCE in order to make sure I had something that works.  Now I'm trying to apply that to a different project, and it's not working ...

Comment: Did you try cloning the project to see if it works on your end?  You'll notice in the previous answer that I linked that we had to remove the glob patterns to get it to work.