# typescript 4.4.4: tsconfig paths not resolving as expected

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "lib": ["ESNext", "ESNext.AsyncIterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "@config": ["src/config"],
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

I am pretty sure there is nothing wrong in tsconfig paths because I even get path autocompletion from my IDE. however when my code is compiled (tsc --project tsconfig.json)

```
import { PRODUCTION } from '@config';

// or

import { PRODUCTION } from '@/config';
```

I get following javascript

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const _config_1 = require("@config");
console.log(_config_1.PRODUCTION);
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

but javascript doesn't understand what "@" is therefore I get "module not found" error. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See this issue on TypeScript's GitHub project: [Module path maps are not resolved in emitted code (#10866)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10866)

## tl;dr

- TypeScript won't rewrite your module paths
- `paths` was designed to help TypeScript understand path aliases used by bundlers
- You'll either need to:

  - use a bundler, such as [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), and configure its own path maps
  - use a build time tool, such as [tspath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tspath), to rewrite the paths
  - modify the runtime module resolver, with something like [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias)

Comment: I was using CRA which comes with webpack configured that's why it worked there but here I am running nodejs and it doesn't. Your answer make sense. Thank you.

Comment: You can use `tsconfig-paths` if you're already using it by [bootstapping it](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths#bootstrapping-with-explicit-params).

Answer (score 14):

I've been stuck with this issue for 2 whole days trying to find something that works. @Wing's answer is correct, if you're using plain `tsc` with no other tools, then Node won't know what you mean by `@/` (or whatever your alias is) in your imports.

I've tried a few different approaches and I've found one that required no configuration.

What **worked**:

At the end of my journey I came across a package that is still actively being maintained: [tsc-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc-alias). The only thing I needed to do was add  `&& tsc-alias -p tsconfig.json` to my `tsc` command in my build script and voilà, it works. So your full command would be something like `tsc -p tsconfig.json && tsc-alias -p tsconfig.json`.

What I tried that **didn't** work:

- I tried "module-alias" and I couldn't get it to work.
- I tried "tsconfig-paths" as suggested by @AlexMorley-Finch with no luck as well. The package seems to be finding the modules but there seems to be a bug that causes the path of the modules not to be mapped correctly (there's an issue open for it).
- I then came across `tscpaths`. This package requires you to explicitly specify your project, src dir and out dir. I got it to work after figuring out my outdir needed to be `./build/src` instead of `./build`. The caveat here: this package hasn't been touched since May 2019 as of writing this.

Comment: works like magic - it's unbelievable how much time I spent for this issue

Comment: How can I use it with nodemon ?