# Is it possible to declare your own typescript modules and import them like npm packages

Tags: javascript, typescript

NPM Packages are imported like this:

```
import { Button, Table } from "@material-ui/core";
```

Which is pretty cool, because the path `"@material-ui/core"` can be compied into other files and still work independently from the copied file's folder structure.

Now I declared my own class, with a lot of exports, which I like to share between a lot of files. For example, I have:

```
root/shared/ui/ui-components.ts
root/app/pages/home/home-page.ts
root/app/pages/home/components/home-tile.ts
```

I'd like to import the `ui-components.ts` file in both the `home-page.ts` and `home-tile.ts` file. Both are imported as following:

for home-page:

```
import { ... } from "../../../shared/ui/ui-components";
```

for home-tile:

```
import { ... } from "../../../../shared/ui/ui-components";
```

Notice we have to go up one folder for the home-tile in order to access the same components. Copying this to other files won't work directly.

Is there a way so I can write

```
import { ... } from "ui-components";
```

in both `home-page.ts` and `home-tile.ts` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can add your application source via paths in tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,  
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      ...,
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "@components/*": ["components/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can import absolutely from app/ or components/ instead of relative to the current file:

```
import {Configuration} from "@components/configurations";
```

**Note:** baseUrl must be specified if paths is

Comment: Thanks! This is what I am looking for. With the right keywords which you provided I was able to find out this question is a duplicate of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281741/how-to-use-paths-in-tsconfig-json). It's so important to know how to spell your question :)