# TypeScript custom paths do not work without barreling

Tags: angular, typescript, path, angular-module

I've spent all morning on [ts-paths](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) to shorten my import paths.

I can confirm that custom paths work IF you setup barreling (an index file exports your modules)

```
root
├── client
│   ├──tsconfig.json
│   ├── src
│       ├──app
│           ├── shared
│               ├── services
│                   ├── some.service.ts
├── common
│   ├── index.ts // exports * from each file
```

My NG8 tsconfig.ts file:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "@common": ["../common"], // works with barreling
        "@services": ["./src/app/shared/services"] // only works with barreling
    },
```

`@services` does not work... unless I setup barreling
(adding an `index.ts` file in `shared` folder with `export * from './some.service';`)

`@common` works out of the box because of barreling like above.

Am I missing something or is everything I've read leaving out a requirement to export your modules in this way?

My research:
https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/shorten-typescript-imports-in-an-angular-project/
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping
[How to use paths in tsconfig.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281741/how-to-use-paths-in-tsconfig-json)
many more...

Comment: This should work, try without the leading `./` Just `"src/app/shared/services"`. Though I think there should be a `tsconfig.json` in the root

Comment: Hey @C_Ogoo so the paths are all correct because it works when an index.ts file exists with service classes exported... Also I've been trying all day with every path variation I can think. Making the path `src/app/shared/services` breaks it... Unless the index with exports exist in which case it still works.

Comment: Ahh i misread / misunderstood .. in the services directory. you dont have a barrel file, but individual fies like `.../services/some-file.ts`

Comment: Yes, I've updated the structure for clarity. There are many service files in that folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the set-up you have (without a barrel `index.ts` file) your paths need to be slightly different.

```
"paths": {
  "@services/*": ["src/app/shared/services/*"],
},
```

You will then be able to import using:

```js
import { SomeService } from '@services/some.service'
```

Comment: This works! I could have sworn that this is exactly how I began early this morning. However, it works now. Thank you for your time and clarification.

Comment: Pleasure, glad I could help :)