# Typescript can't find module on compile

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get path resolution to work in typescript.

My folder structure so far looks like this:

- src:

  - index.ts
  - types:

    - global.d.ts
    - cache.d.ts
  - util:

    - index.ts
    - Cache.ts

Since It's getting pretty nested I would like to be able to access for example the util folder by typing
`import { Whatever } from '@util'`. I've tried setting `baseUrl` to `./src` and `paths` to `"@util": ["util/index"]` with `moduleResolution` set to `node`.

This is how my files look so far:

**src/index.ts**

```
import {Cache} from '@util'

const c = new Cache();
```

**src/util/index.ts**

```
export { default as Cache } from './Cache';
```

**src/util/Cache.ts**

```
export default class {
// class code goes here
}
```

Now, the compiler doesn't complain while I'm coding in VS Code but when I run `tsc` in the command line I get an error saying that it can't find the module '@util'.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why I can't compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, in the end I managed to solve it by using [tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths).

Because I wasn't using a bundler like webpack my custom paths weren't getting compiled along with the rest of the code. So instead of having resolved paths to the modules there would just a string looking like the path from the original source (`import {Whatever} from '@util'` instad of `/absolute/path/to/@util/index`).

You use `tsconfig-paths` by preloading it's `register` script when you call node/ts-node from the command line with the -r option (for example `node -r tsconfig-paths/register dist/index.js`). This converts the paths accordingly after emit.

Answer (score -1):

what you are trying to import is a namespaced NPM package here while what you actually want to do is do a relative or absolute import i.e.:

```typescript
import {Cache} from './util'

const c = new Cache();
```

For better understanding of the '@' import check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36667439/1954884)

Comment: thanks for the answer however I don't want to import them by using a relative/absolute import, I want to make the `paths` field from `tsconfig.json` work so I can import them without thinking about where the modules are located. It doesn't have to be called `@module` it can be just `module`, i.e. `util`

Comment: than they need to be NPM dependencies whatever you define in tsconfig JSON is then resolved using relative/absolute imports

Comment: I made a repl (https://repl.it/repls/LostPassionateSet) to show my files + tsconfig. I think I'm doing it right and it should work but It just doesn't

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281741/how-to-use-paths-in-tsconfig-json