# How can I import an enum through an intermediate TS file?

Tags: typescript, enums, static-typing

I file A I have:

```
export enum MyFluffyEnum { Beauty, Courage, Love }
```

In file B I have:

```
import { MyFluffyEnum } from "./A";

export type { MyFluffyEnum };
```

In file C I have:

```
import { MyFluffyEnum } from "./B";
```

Compile-time error:

`'MyFluffyEnum' cannot be used as a value because it was exported using 'export type'.`

If I put a separate `export { MyFluffyEnum };` in the file B (the intermediate file) I get the error "Module not found: Can't resolve 'B.tsx' in 'my-project/path/here'".

**If I import the file with the enum as named export directly, then there is no error.**

Links that may be relevant:

1. [Export enum from user defined typescript path result in Module not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63942578/export-enum-from-user-defined-typescript-path-result-in-module-not-found)
2. https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin/issues/78

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67954253/258462) solved the problem:

> I was having a WebPack config file that was not actually used. I was
> actually using CRA. So I started using
> [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) and
> WebPack v4 as an intermediate solution till I start using "pure"
> WebPack. In `config-overrides.js` I put:
>
> ```js
> require("tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin");
>
> module.exports = {
>   webpack: function(config, env) {
>     return {
>       ...config,
>       resolve: {
>         ...config.resolve,
>         plugins: [
>           ...config.resolve.plugins,
>           new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
>             extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
>           }),
>         ],
>       },
>     };
>   },
> };
> ```
>
> After migrating to
> [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) and
> making this change, the `Failed to compile.` error is gone. This also
> solves the issue in [How can I import an enum through an intermediate TS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67949040/258462).