# eslint parsing error: Cannot read file 'c:\user\repo\ts-project\tsconfig.json' after setup with firebase

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, eslint

My eslint can't find my my tsconfig.json file because it expects it to be at the top level (like listed in the title) but instead its at `ts-project/firebase/tsconfig.json`. However if I just copy it and place it in the top level it still doesn't work.

How can I tell eslint that the correct path is `ts-project/firebase/tsconfig.json` instead of `ts-project/tsconfig.json`

Comment: May it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281741/how-to-use-paths-in-tsconfig-json