# How can I get VSCode auto-imports working in a TypeScript monorepo?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, monorepo

I have a very simple TypeScript monorepo with the following structure:

```
project/
└── packages/
    |── client/
    ├── server/
    |   └── src/
    |       └── main.ts
    └── common/
        └── src/
            └── main.ts
```

The server has a package.json file with:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "common": "file:../common"
  },
```

And the code looks like this:

```
// in file: common/src/main.ts
export class Foo() {}
```

```
// in file: server/src/main.ts
const foo = new Foo();
```

When I open VSCode, put the cursor over `Foo`, and do Ctrl+Space, it doesn't find any imports. But if I manually add `import { Foo } from "common"` to the top of the file, it compiles and works just fine. Why doesn't auto-import work? How can I make it work?

For reference, the above reprex is available to download in a repo located here: https://github.com/Zamiell/test-monorepo

Comment: FWIW, IntelliJ also does not recognize custom paths but does recognize a local npm dependency, since it ends up in node_modules anyway

Comment: I don't understand your comment, can you clarify? In the above question, you can see that I am using a local NPM dependency. Local NPM dependency do end up in node_modules. but only as a symlink. I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "custom paths".

Comment: I'm just saying it should work, IntelliJ makes it work. [Custom paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281741/how-to-use-paths-in-tsconfig-json) are a way to avoid long `../../../../../` in your imports but IntelliJ does not recognize that correctly and always adds the `../../../../` instead of the custom path config I've added in tsconfig.