# Why doesn't the exports field of npm work in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

Our library [@ltonetwork/lto](https://github.com/ltonetwork/lto-api.js), is written in typescript. We use `tsc` to compile to javascript in the `lib` folder.

The package contains several sub-packages, which are located in subfolders that contain an index.ts file.

When trying to import a submodule, like this

```js
import {Transfer} from "@ltonetwork/lto/transactions";
```

I'm expecting this to work, but I get the following error

```
test.ts:1:24 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@ltonetwork/lto/transactions' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

The package.json of @ltonetwork/lto contains

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc -p ./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "main": "lib",
  "exports": {
    ".": "./lib/index.js",
    "./*": "./lib/*/index.js",
    "./package.json": "./package.json"
  },
  "files": [
    "lib",
    "interfaces.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

and the tsconfig.json is

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "baseUrl": "",
    "lib": ["es2017.object", "es2015", "es6", "dom"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "paths": {},
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "lib"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

I've tried to explicitly name the submodules, instead of using wildcards in `exports`, but that made no difference.

What am I doing wrong that's causing this import issue?

---

Edit:
**This is not related to monorepos or yarn workspaces.** This is about using the `exports` field in npm with typescript 4.7.1-rc. This feature wasn't working with earlier versions of typescript.

For more information see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33079

I've also tried

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc -p ./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "main": "lib",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "require": {
        "default": "./lib/index.js",
        "types": "./lib/index.d.ts"
      },
      "import": {
        "default": "./lib/index.js",
        "types": "./lib/index.d.ts"
      }
    },
    "./transactions": {
      "require": {
        "default": "./lib/transactions/index.js",
        "types": "./lib/transactions/index.d.ts"
      },
      "import": {
        "default": "./lib/transactions/index.js",
        "types": "./lib/transactions/index.d.ts"
      }
    },
    "./package.json": "./package.json"
  },
  "files": [
    "lib",
    "interfaces.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe the tsconfig.json->paths config is missing. I think you need to config paths, if you reference resources with "@".
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281741/how-to-use-paths-in-tsconfig-json

Comment: You're describing a monorepo. Take a look at [Yarn workspaces](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/) or [Bolt](https://github.com/boltpkg/bolt). Both of these will symlink your internal dependencies, so when you import them, as far as TypeScript is concerned, you're importing from `node_modules`. Also take a look at the [Monorepo Guide](https://monorepo.guide/).

Comment: A monorepo isn't what I try to accomplish. These aren't individual packages.

Comment: Are all runtimes using ts4.7+? and `lib` folder contains all the right files etc?

Comment: If I do `tsc --version` the output is `Version 4.7.1-rc`. Is there anything else I'd need to update? Yes, the lib folder contains the right files.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ensure `moduleResolution` in the consuming library is set to either `Node16` or `NodeNext` in your `tsconfig.json` file.

Edit: `bundler` is now also an option.

Comment: Thanks. Is that required for my library, for the project that uses the library, or for both? I'm getting this error for just about every import in my lib. Do I need to rewrite all the imports?
`Relative import paths need explicit file extensions in EcmaScript imports when '--moduleResolution' is 'node16' or 'nodenext'`

Comment: Users of the library must all specify it otherwise typescript won't be able to find the typings on their end. You don't need to use it when writing the library itself (unless you want to make self references) but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: adding moduleResolution didn't change a thing for me. I am running basically the same setup.

Comment: I LOVE YOU! me funciono gracias

Comment: Now I have to add in .js extension to every imports. Facepalm. 2023 and tooling gets more complicated. I went back to typesVersions

Comment: `moduleResolution: bundler` if you don't want to have to add `.js` extensions.

Comment: It wasn't working for me even with this, my problem was that I had not put a dot slash in front of `./` the exported-file: `"./svg": "dist/svg.js"`. This works fine for `node` and for the main export (`"."`), but TypeScript don't understand it. So you need `"./svg": "./dist/svg.js"`, the `./` is important!

Answer (score 4):

Since Typescript 3.1 we've been able to do this and it doesn't require the consumer to have a `tsconfig.json`.

```json
"typesVersions": {
    "*": {
        "path1": [ "./path/to/path1.d.ts" ],
        "path2": [ "./path/to/path2.d.ts" ],        
    }
},
```

This may only work with named submodules.

Comment: I love you mate. I'm struggling since yesterday to fix this