# Typescript path to referenced folder

Tags: typescript

I am trying to declare a path to a referenced folder which will enable me to write a shorter import statement. how can i make it work with the @resources path

- I am building from /server by running tsc -b

app.ts

this long statement works

```
import IEntity from 
  '../../model/src/resources/entity/entity.interface';
```

this sort one does **NOT** work

```
import IEntity from 
  '@resources/entity/entity.interface';
```

folder structure:

```
/
 /model
   /src
     /resources
       /entitiy
         entity.interface.ts
 tsconfig.json 
 /server
   /src
     app.ts
 tsconfig.json
```

entity.interface.ts

```
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export default interface IEntity extends Document {
   name: string;
}
```

tsconfig.json (under /server)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    // "rootDir": "./",
    // "composite": true,          
    // "isolatedModules": true, 
    "strict": true,
    // "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
       "@resources" : ["../model/src/resources"]    
     },
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true    
 },
 "include": ["src/**/*"],
 "references": [{
   "path": "../model/"
 }]
}
```

tsconfig.json (under /model)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
 "baseUrl": ".",                      
 "paths": {
    "@resources/*" : ["../model/src/resources/*"]    
 }
```

based on this answer: [How to use paths in tsconfig.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281741/how-to-use-paths-in-tsconfig-json)

thanks @MisterFridge