# Using compilerOptions: paths does not work with node

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsconfig

Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281741/how-to-use-paths-in-tsconfig-json), but *not* a duplicate IMHO when using `node`:

```
$ tree .                                        
.
├── src
│   ├── main.ts
│   └── utils
│       └── myUtils.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

I'm trying to use a `@` import like so:

```bash
$ cat src/main.ts 
import { myLovelyUtilsFunction } from "@folder1/myUtils"
const y = myLovelyUtilsFunction();
console.log(`>>> ${y}`);
```

My `tsconfig.json` looks right, mapping `@folder1` where it should:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": { "@folder1/*": ["utils/*"] },
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

Transpilation goes *fine*, but running `node` *doesn't*:

```bash
$ npx tsc -p tsconfig.json # <--- no errors
$ node src/main.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@folder1/myUtils'
Require stack:
< ... omitted ... >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `tsconfig-paths` or `ts-node`to get your module resolution work properly.

Modify your `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": { "@folder1/*": ["src/utils/*"] },
    "module": "commonjs"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

You also need to create an entry file point, which will use tsconfig-paths to resolve the paths.

```
index.ts

import 'tsconfig-paths/register';
import './src/main';
```

Update your `package.json` and then run to test.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  }
}
```

The structure of your project could look like this now

```
.
├── src/
│   ├── main.ts
│   ├── utils/
│   │   └── myUtils.ts
├── tsconfig.json
├── package.json
├── index.ts
```

Comment: is `index.ts` mandatory?

Comment: Its not mandatory, but its a common approach to set up tsconfig-paths in nodejs. U can always handle this directly in your nodejs start script in your package.json file.

`{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts"
  }
}`

Comment: I didn't need to use `package.json`, just `import 'tsconfig-paths/register'`.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you replace
`"paths": { "@folder1/*": ["utils/*"] }`
with `"paths": { "folder1/*": "./src/utils/*"] }`
and then `import { myLovelyUtilsFunction } from "@folder1/myUtils"`
by `import { myLovelyUtilsFunction } from "folder1/myUtils"`
will work.
Source: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths